# Create .cer file from certificate values

Tags: ssl, iis, https, certificate

I want to have ssl certificate on my IIS server, so I get on my Mail letter from reg.ru with:

You certificate is presented below: (original language: Ваш сертификат предоставлен ниже)

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

[values]

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Root certificate (original language: Корневой сертификат)

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

[values]

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Intermediate certificate (original language: Промежуточный сертификат)

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

[values]

-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Request for a certificate (original language: Запрос на получение сертификата)

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

[values]

-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

Save the private key on the local computer (original language:Сохраните приватный ключ на локальном компьютере.)

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

[values]

-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

But my IIS requires .cer file, what have I to do to get .cer file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I find a solution

1. go here
   https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html
2. create pfx file from first certificate, private key, Intermediate certificate and root sertificate
3. click import in iis server sertificates page and select this file.

(Maybe my problem because of service reg.ru)